TypeScript path alias not working with Vite
Hey guys I have created simple TypeScript project using the Vite CLI. Unfortunately when doing so Vite didn't generate a vite.config that I could use to add path aliases to my project.
What I want to achive:
I just want to use "@/*" instead of "./src/*".
My tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    /* Path alias */
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "types/global.d.ts"]
}

Again there is no vite.config as I used this CLI command to generate the project:
bun create vite my-ts-app --template vanilla-ts

I tried adding path alias option to my tsconfig.json file and restarted both VSCode and TS Server but with no success:
    /* Path alias */
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }


Figure it out.
You need to create a new file called: vite.config.ts and add this to it:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { resolve } from "node:path";

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
});


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
